# Cannot update old entries after adding columns to the table Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-migrations

I have a rails app which is already running with some users, users that I cannot delete.

Now I have added a couple of columns to the user table(like last name, nickname).

The problem is that although new sign ups can change there profile information the existing ones cannot change them.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a stupid mistake because of which it was not updating the entries in the profile.

I added new columns few of which were mandatory at the time of signup but were not mandatory when updating the profile (eg:- Date of Birth) as we thought no one would like to change their date of birth :)

So when the existing user were trying to update their profile the date of birth field was getting failed at the backend because of the validation which we had applied.

Figured it out by checking the console.

Answer (score 0):

So, users are not able to update any of their information? Or the fields are not showing up?

If the fields are not showing up, go to:

```
app/views/users/edit.html.erb
```

And look where the form is coming from, you will most likely need to add the fields there or in

```
app/views/users/_form.html.erb
```

---

Now, if the users cannot edit there information, you either need to create the mechanism to do so (users#edit and users#update) or update the records yourself in the migration. If you can't do either of those things, it's a design flaw :)

Comment: I can see the newly added fields. If I create a new user I can update the profile information as well, however for the existing users (i.e the users who had signed up before adding the new fields) I cannot update any information in their profile. It actually shows that the information is updated but when I return back to the profile page I see that nothing has been updated.

Comment: What does the updat method look like?

Comment: actually I just figured out the problem, it was because of a field in which I have added validation which was required at the signup but did not include it in the profile setting so although it was showing that your profile was updated successfully it was not storing the information as at the backend the validation was getting failed